# When field is hidden output says array

Tags: php

When i run the following code and the type=text then i see a series of images from a folder. When the type=hidden it will only show the word array. What have i done wrong?

```
<input type=button onClick="location.href='bush.php'" value='click here'>

<?php
$string = file_get_contents('ind2610.html');



$start = 'Record Id:';
$end = '</tr>';



?>
<?
$startpos = strpos($string, $start) + strlen($start);

if (strpos($string, $start) !== false)

{
$endpos = strpos($string, $end, $startpos);


if (strpos($string, $end, $startpos) !== false)
{
    //echo substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
}
    $number= substr($string, $startpos, $endpos - $startpos);
}
$notag=strip_tags("$number");
?>

<form  name="the" method="GET" action="display.php">
user ID: <input  name="fname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $notag ; ?>">         <br>
<input name="user" type="submit"  alt="Submit">

</form>

 looking at: <input  name="f" type="text" value="<?php echo $notag ; ?>"><br>
looking at:number <input  name="f" type="text" value="<?php echo $number ; ?   >"><br>

<?


?>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: why do you have same `name` for two differrent fields ?

Comment: To make stuff clear, why are you making the fname input type=hidden?

Comment: Making the fname hidden so that users dont see the input box. There are bits of code in there so i can see what is happening. Cant see same name for two fields?